# Multiple checkboxes into database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code which allows the user to select multiple check-boxes.

```
while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"pid[]\" value=\"{$data2['product_id']}\">         {$data2['product_id']} {$data2['product_name']}</option>";
    echo"<br/>";
}
```

I want to enter the checked values in the database.

```
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($pid); $i++) {

    $information="INSERT INTO     orders(productid,product_discount,amount,customerid,order_date,quantity) VALUES('$pid','$discount','$amount','$custid',CURDATE(),'')";
    $result=mysql_query($information) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

This is not working.

Comment: if you want to insert the same product info for different pid's.. check my answer.

Comment: better echo $information and see what is problem...

Comment: `is not working` is not a problem description.  Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for SQL injection.

`mysql_*` are deprecated; use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since $pid is an array, you cannot insert it as it is. Try this :

```
$pid=$_POST['pid'];
for ($i=0;$i<count($pid);$i++)
{

$information="INSERT INTO     orders(productid,product_discount,amount,customerid,order_date,quantity) VALUES($pid[$i],'$discount','$amount','$custid',CURDATE(),'')";
$result=mysql_query($information) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST['pid'] as $pid) {
 $information="INSERT INTO
                  orders(productid,product_discount,amount,customerid,order_date,quantity) 
               VALUES('$pid','$discount','$amount','$custid',CURDATE(),'')";
 $result=mysql_query($information) or die(mysql_error());
}
```